# Spring Cloud Config is unable to parse configs required for Spring Cloud Gateway globalcors

Tags: yaml, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-gateway, spring-cloud-config-server

I configured a Spring Cloud Config which uses a GIT repository to centeralize all configurations in one place. including configs that are required by Spring Cloud Gateway.

Spring Cloud Gateway requires some configs for managing CORS. these configs contains url patterns as shown below:

```
spring:
  cloud:
    gateway:
      globalcors:
        corsConfigurations:
          '[/**]':
            allowedOrigins: "https://docs.spring.io"
            allowedMethods:
            - GET
```

This code has been copied from Spring Cloud docs page `https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-gateway/2.1.x/multi/multi__cors_configuration.html`

When I add this code to gateway configuration file, Spring Cloud Config generates below error in console:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid character found in method name [0x030x000x00/*0xe00x000x000x000x000x00Cookie: ]. HTTP method names must be tokens
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer.parseRequestLine(Http11InputBuffer.java:419) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:272) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:859) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1734) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar!/:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]
```

and the output page is:

[image]

But when I remove patten part, I got config without any problems but without required configs

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: What version are you using?

Comment: I use spring boot 3.0.4

Comment: And spring cloud version?

Comment: Spring Cloud 2022.0.1

Comment: Can you upgrade to the latest and try again?